# Why giving read access to account.analytic enables menu "Project / Invoicing / Contracts to Renew"?

Tags: odoo

I saw that giving read acces to Analytic Account to a group, it automatically enables the menu Project / Invoicing / Contracts to Renew to users assigned to that group.
Even if that menu if not part of the Menu list of the group

Is there any way to avoid that? Or how can I delete that menu entry to that group ?
because that's exactly what I don't want, to give access to Analytic Account views to this group, but this group needs read access to account.analytic to be able to create task works and timesheet lines

Answer (score 0):

First Here, Analytic Account read right are the access right(operational level security) for the model (whether use can create read, write or unlink )not fro the menu, so what you can do it :

Create one extra group which will disable this menu for the use and assign that group for that group only so if you want shoe that menu assign that group to particular user and else do nto assign the group tp the user so that user will nto see it.

Else you have to do is if you have your seperate fork then on that menu user the `groups=""` attribute to make sure that only which group can see it.

Regards

Comment: that's what I did. I create a new group with access to Project Menu only, then I added account.analytic read permissions only and automatically the Menu Project / Invoicing / Contracts To Renew was displayed for the user belonging to that group. I've never added the menu to the group.

Comment: but igving read write to the model doe snot means yoa re giving read right for the menu

Comment: Hello Follow this URL and under stand the groups attribute here http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_7_menu_action/7_1_menus.html